# titanium studio

Tags: titanium-mobile

Dear friends,
             I am new to titanium studio...i have some doubts..please help me out...

1. I am working on windows xp os,i tried to get iphone platform enabled in titanium studio but I am not possible to do that is there any solution..
2. Will I be able to run the program in iphone platform in windows os ....
3. I have tried doing it for android platform by installing sdk,jdk and titanium studio..I am able to work with web and desktop applications but for mobile applications, when I create one and just try to run it it throws some error, I am not able to launch the emulator...please help me out...
4. Can u just explain the way howto install titaniumstudio,sdk,jdk....for android or iphone platforrm.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions,

1.) Titanium for Windows is not capable of building an iPhone application.  I use both a Mac and a Windows machine with Titanium Studio on it.  I create my iPhone/Android friendly projects on the Mac, and am able to edit them on my PC.  To test on the iPhone or in the Simulator, I have to run the project from the Mac.  Windows has no way of doing this.

2.) Refer to #1

3.) You must install the Android SDK, follow the instructions for installing it properly and downloading the necessary packages.  You must then tell Titanium where the Android SDK is located under:

```
Window->Preferences->Titanium Studio->Titanium
```

4.) Refer to the Appcelerator 'Getting Started' documentation.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/get_started

Answer (score 0):

For your question 1,2,3.

You have no method to run a iOS in windows machine. Titanium for windows is andriod only. If you like to develop in both Android and iOS. You need a Mac.

For your question 4, titanium have a good documentation for how to start.

You may refer http://developer.appcelerator.com/get_started